# Can not Search in and Edit DB in the same times (and same Windows Form) by using DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm have DataGridView in a Windows Form with some data in it and I have button for edit, I want to search for row by using TextBox and button and when I find the wanted row I will change it and click edit button,when I edit any row (without using search button) and press edit the DB is Updated , my problem is that: when I search for specific row and find it then edit the data and press edit button the data in DB don't updated, please help, I'm use this code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form9
Private sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Clinic System\Clinic System\ClinicDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Private cmdSelect, cmdDelete As String
Private daEmployees As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From History", sqlConn)
Private sqlCmndBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(daEmployees)
Private myDS As New DataSet

Private Sub HistoryBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Me.Validate()
    Me.HistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ClinicDBDataSet3)

End Sub

Private Sub Form9_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        daEmployees.Fill(myDS, "History")
        HistoryDataGridView.DataSource = myDS.Tables(0)

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSearch.Click

    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Clinic System\Clinic System\ClinicDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim d1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from History Where Name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)
        Dim d2 As New DataTable
        d1.Fill(d2)
        HistoryDataGridView.DataSource = d2

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Err.Discription")
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonEdit.Click

    daEmployees.Update(myDS.Tables(0))
    MsgBox("Patient Details Updated!")


End Sub
```

Comment: Your logic is not completely clear. If you already have data in the grid, why you create new table and search in DB, if you could search in the loaded data?

Comment: My DB contains large number of rows, so I need to search about specific row by "Name" and when I find the row I will edit it.

Comment: When the row exist in the the firsts rows (no need to search), I can edit the row's data without any problem.

Comment: when I find the row "by search" and make edit on it, the DB don't updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is rather simple - you trying to update wrong table

```
daEmployees.Update(myDS.Tables(0))
```

While you need to update `d2`

In form scope

```
Dim _isSearch as boolean
```

On `Form9_Load` and when you reload as well

```
_isSearch = false
```

Here what you can do - In `ButtonSearch_Click`

```
_isSearch = true
If myDS.Tables.Contains("SEARCH_TBL") Then  
    myDS.Tables.Remove("SEARCH_TBL")
End if
Dim d2 As DataTable = myDS.Tables.Add("SEARCH_TBL")
d1.Fill(d2)
```

In `ButtonEdit_Click`

```
if _isSearch then
    daEmployees.Update(myDS.Tables("SEARCH_TBL"))
else 
    daEmployees.Update(myDS.Tables(0))
End if
```

I think, `daEmployees` should update "SEARCH_TBL" because result set identical to first table. If not, just take your other adapter to a form scope.

But really, you can reuse the grid and update button, but you need to create logic tracking which table is currently loaded.